# Call to MemoryStream.GetBuffer() succeeds even after MemoryStream.Close(); Why?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, memorystream

I have found the following construct in some open-source code:

```
var mstream = new MemoryStream();
// ... write some data to mstream
mstream.Close();
byte[] b = mstream.GetBuffer();
```

I thought this code would have "unexpected" behavior and maybe throw an exception, since the call to `Close` should effectively be a call to `Dispose` according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stream.close.aspx).

However, as far as I have been able to tell from experimenting, the call to `GetBuffer()` always succeeds and returns a valid result, even if I `Thread.Sleep` for 20 seconds or enforce garbage collection via `GC.Collect()`.

*Should* the call to `GetBuffer()` succeed even after `Close`/`Dispose`? In that case, why is not the underlying buffer released in the `MemoryStream` disposal?

Comment: Just a side-note - `GetBuffer` will get you the whole buffer, including any padding that's there for growth. If the stream wasn't initialized with fixed capacity, this probably means you've got zeroes at the end you don't want. That said, `GetBuffer` only works when the buffer size is fixed, if I'm reading the code correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It doesn't need to. The buffer is managed memory, so normal garbage collection will deal with it, without needing to be included in the disposal.
2. It's useful to be able to get the bytes of the memory stream, even after the stream has been closed (which may have happened automatically after the steam was passed to a method that writes something to a stream and then closes said stream). And for that to work, the object needs to hold onto the buffer along with a record of how much had been written to it.

In considering the second point, it actually makes more sense in a lot of cases to call `ToArray()` (which as said, requires the in-memory store that `GetBuffer()` returns to still be alive) **after** you've closed the stream, because having closed the stream guarantees that any further attempt to write to the stream will fail. Hence if you have a bug where you obtain the array too early, it will throw an exception rather than just give you incorrect data. (Obviously if you explicitly want to get the current array part-way through the stream operations, that's another matter). It also guarantees that all streams are fully flushed rather than having part of their data in a temporary buffer (`MemoryStream` isn't buffered because `MemoryStream` essentially *is* a buffer, but you may have been using it with chained streams or writers that had their own separate buffer).

Answer (score 5):

Technically there's nothing to dispose in  `MemoryStream`. Literally nothing, it doesn't have operating system handles, unmanaged resources, nothing. it is just a wrapper around `byte[]`. All what you can do is set the `buffer`(internal array)  to `null`, that BCL team hasn't done for some reason.

As @mike noted in comments BCL team wanted `GetBuffer` and `ToArray` to work, even after disposed, though we're not sure why?. [Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs#0b83d17ca69bf8ea#references).

Here's how `Dispose` implemented.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try {
        if (disposing) {
            _isOpen = false;
            _writable = false;
            _expandable = false;
            // Don't set buffer to null - allow GetBuffer & ToArray to work.
    #if FEATURE_ASYNC_IO
                        _lastReadTask = null;
    #endif
        }
    }
    finally {
        // Call base.Close() to cleanup async IO resources
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

and `GetBuffer` is below

```
public virtual byte[] GetBuffer()
{
    if (!this._exposable)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(Environment.GetResourceString("UnauthorizedAccess_MemStreamBuffer"));
    }
    return this._buffer;
}
```

As you can see in `Dispose` `_buffer` is untouched, and in `GetBuffer` no disposed checks.

Comment: In fact, the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs#0b83d17ca69bf8ea#references) has comment about this: "Don't set buffer to null - allow GetBuffer & ToArray to work."

Comment: The reason the `buffer` isn't set to null is probably that it doesn't have any effect on garbage collection in normal operation (you'd use the memory stream in a using, so the `buffer` would be out of scope as soon as the stream itself). Also, when you use `MemoryStream` in a stream chain, you want to be able to get to the data after you close everything.

Comment: @mikez Thanks, I was looking into reflector. Updated my answer with reference source.

Answer (score 1):

Since the GC is non-deterministic you cannot force it to immediately dispose the MemoryStream, thus the instance will not be marked as disposed immediately, instead it will just be marked for disposal. This means that for some time, until it is really disposed you can use some of its functions. Since it keeps a strong reference to its buffer you can get it, here is what the GetBuffer method looks like:

```
public virtual byte[] GetBuffer()
{
    if (!this._exposable)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(Environment.GetResourceString("UnauthorizedAccess_MemStreamBuffer"));
    }
    return this._buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most interface methods, the `IDisposable.Dispose` does not promise to do anything.  Instead, it provides a standard means by which the owner of an object can let that object know that its services are no longer required, in case the object might need to make use of that information.  If an object has asked outside entities to do something on its behalf, and has promised those outside entities that it will let *them* know when *their* services are no longer required, its `Dispose` method can relay the notification to those entities.

If an object has a method which can only be performed while the object has outside entities acting on its behalf, an attempt to call that method after those entities have been dismissed should throw an `ObjectDisposedException` *rather than failing in some other way*.  Further, if there is a method which cannot possibly be useful after the entity is dismissed, it should often throw `ObjectDisposedException` even if a particular didn't actually need to use the entity.  On the other hand, if a particular call would have a sensible meaning after an object has dismissed all entities that were acting on its behalf, there's no particular reason why such a call shouldn't be allowed to succeed.

I would view the `ObjectDisposedException` much like I view the collection-modified `InvalidOperationException` of `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()`: if some condition (either `Dispose`, or modification of a collection, respectively) would prevent a method from behaving "normally", the method is allowed to throw the indicated exception, and is not allowed to behave in some other erroneous fashion.  On the other hand, if the method is capable of achieving its objectives without difficulty, and if doing so would make sense, such behavior should be considered just as acceptable as would be throwing an exception.  In general, objects are not required to operate under such adverse conditions, but sometimes it may be helpful for them to do so [e.g. enumeration of a `ConcurrentDictionary` will not be invalidated by changes to the collection, since such invalidation would make concurrent enumeration useless].